# Cauchy sequence and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

A sequence is said to be Cauchy sequence if for given any integer n, there exists a positive real number R, such that for any n1, n2 > n, mod{n1th term - n2th term}

1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0........

Now for any integer n,  whenever n1,n2 >n mod{n1th term - n2th term} < or equal to 1.
So as per the definition of a Cauchy  sequence we can say that this sequence is a Cauchy sequence, however, this is not a convergent sequence. How come?
This implies there is gap in my understanding, can anyone kindly point out where am I wrong?.

---

Edited version:

A sequence $(a_n)$ is said to be Cauchy sequence if for given any integer $n$, there exists a positive real number $R$, such that for any $n_1, n_2 > n$, $|a_{n_1}-a_{n_2}|<R$.

We can prove that every Cauchy sequence is a convergent sequence.

Now let us consider the following sequence,
$1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$

Now for any integer $n$,  whenever $n_1,n_2 >n$ we have  $|a_{n_1}-a_{n_2}|\le 1$ .

So as per the definition of a Cauchy  sequence we can say that this sequence is a Cauchy sequence, however, this is not a convergent sequence. How come?

This implies there is gap in my understanding, can anyone kindly point out where am I wrong?.

Comment: It would be better if you could accept the answers for your previous questions before people answer this particular question.

Comment: Primeczar: Pleas have a look at the edited version, whether this is what you wanted to ask. (I was not sure what you meant by "mod".)

Answer (score 8):

I think your problem is that you work with incorrect definition of Cauchy sequence. The correct definition is the following:

> A sequence $(a_n)$ is said to be Cauchy sequence if for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $n$, such that for any $n_1, n_2 > n$ the inequality $|a_{n_1}-a_{n_2}|<\varepsilon$ holds.

Now if you choose $\varepsilon=\frac12$, you can see that your sequence $1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$ is not a Cauchy sequence.