# Question regarding Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am working on a problem in sequences. The theorem I am trying to prove requires the following implication. But I am not sure how to prove this. Kindly share your thoughts.

Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence which is not Cauchy but satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(y_n,y_{n+1})=0$. Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb N$, there exists an odd integer $q(n)\in \mathbb N$ and an even integer $p(n) \in \mathbb N$ with $n<p(n)<q(n)$, satisfying $d(y_{p(n)},y_{q(n)})\ge \epsilon$ and $d(y_{q(n)-1},y_{p(n)})< \epsilon$.

Thank you.

Comment: Why such sequence need to be convergent? Please explain. I am not even assuming yn is cauchy

Comment: Never mind, I initially misread the question. My apologies!

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such a sequence? (I may also be misunderstanding what Cauchy means.)

Comment: I might be wrong, but by this definition of a Cauchy sequence: "A sequence $(a_n)$ is said to be Cauchy sequence if for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $n$, such that for any $n_1, n_2 > n$ the inequality $|a_{n_1}-a_{n_2}|<\varepsilon$ holds," it seems that $y_n$ cannot exist...? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86050/cauchy-sequence-and-convergence?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false as stated: we cannot make demands on the parity of the indicies $p(n)$ and $q(n)$. To see a counterexample, define $y_n$ as follows. For each $n$, write $n = 2k + r$ with $r \in \{0,1\}$ and define $\sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{1}{j}$. Then $y_n$ satisfy that $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(y_n, y_{n+1}) = 0$ and the $y_n$ are not Cauchy as they are a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ that does not converge.

On the other hand, for all $k$ odd, $y_k= y_{k-1}$ so for any integer $m$, $d(y_{m}, y_k) = d(y_m, y_{k-1})$, which rules out the desired feature for odd and even indicies from occuring for any $\epsilon > 0$.